# Width of HTML body changes when ng-view includes multiple rows in Bootstrap container

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, yeoman-generator-angular

I used the Yeoman angular-generator to create an AngularJS app with Bootstrap.

When I use more than a certain number of Bootstrap rows in a partial view, the HTML body width suddenly gets smaller and throws out the alignment.

I have been able to recreate the problem by generating an app from scratch as follows:

```
mkdir mytodo && cd $_
yo angular
? Would you like to use Gulp (experimental) instead of Grunt? No
? Would you like to use Sass (with Compass)? No
? Would you like to include Bootstrap? Yes
? Which modules would you like to include? angular-resource.js, angular-route.js
```

If I replace the HTML in 'about.html' with 26 Bootstrap rows, the HTML body width is 1224px, as expected:

[image: 26 Bootstrap rows in about.html]

[image: HTML Body is 1224px]

If I then add just one more row, the body size suddenly decreases by 15px to 1209px, as follows:

[image: One extra Bootstrap row, now 27 in total]

[image: HTML Body is reduced to 1209px]

The problem also happens with fewer rows if the rows contain more detail. Here I stripped the problem down to the bare bones in the hope that someone can reproduce it as well and guide me to a solution.

Note that 'main.css' and all other code is exactly as generated by Yeoman, except for 'about.html'.

The various relevant versions are: node v6.4.0; npm 3.10.6; yo 1.8.4; bower 1.7.9; grunt-cli v1.2.0; grunt v0.4.5; Bootstrap v3.3.7; AngularJS v1.5.8

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the code had a Bootstrap container nested inside a container-fluid, which is disallowed because of padding and so on (see the Bootstrap [discussion](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) on Containers).

I removed the offending container and the problem was solved.